# Make format string align integer after character

Tags: python, string, format, format-string

I'm trying to make a format string that does something like the following.

```
I lost 10 turtles        Total: 20 Turtles
I lost  5 turtles        Total: 15 Turtles
```

I came up with this string `"I lost {:>2} {:<13}Total:{:<}".format(10,"turtles",20)` is there anyway to get rid of the `{:<13}` and `[,"turtles"]` but still produce the same result?

Comment: its very clear just replace `{:<13}` with `turtles` do you want this ?

Comment: I also thought it was the thing to do, however the alignment is not uniform when done that way. It's the `{:<13}` that is needed, what I would want is for the first integer to have it's own type, turtles.

Comment: what about `"I lost {:<13} Total:{:<}".format("10 turtles","20 turtles")` ?

Comment: That works good when you only have the same amount of decimal places, however for 5 turtles lost, the alignment is lost. I could format the strings in the format, but for now I'm using the answer @falsetru provided.

Comment: i add and an answer have a look !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `turtles` inside the format string:

```
>>> "I lost {:>2} {:<13}Total:{:<}".format(10, "turtles", 20)
'I lost 10 turtles      Total:20'
>>> "I lost {:>2} turtles      Total:{:<}".format(10, 20)  # <--------
'I lost 10 turtles      Total:20'

>>> "I lost {:>2} {:<13}Total:{:<} Turtles".format(10, "turtles", 20)
'I lost 10 turtles      Total:20 Turtles'
>>> "I lost {:>2} turtles      Total:{:<} Turtles".format(10, 20)  # <--------
'I lost 10 turtles      Total:20 Turtles'
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm currently doing my question is if there is anyway to remove it. I feel like the formatter doesn't have to replace something that is always going to be the same thing.

Comment: @Emilgardis, See the second and the fourth code lines.

Comment: Yes that would work, but it does seem like a rather stupid solution(in the way that you put in the spaces yourself)

Answer (score 0):

what about this ?:

```
>>> "I lost {:<20} Total:{:<}".format("10 turtles","20 turtles")
'I lost 10 turtles           Total:20 turtles'
```

or a function :

```
>>> def formater(i,j):
...  return "I lost {:<20} Total:{:<}".format("{} turtles".format(i),"{} Turtles".format(j))
... 
>>> formater(10,20)
'I lost 10 turtles           Total:20 Turtles'
```

Comment: Would work if the first format of the first string in the first format(long sentence) was `"{:2} turtles"`.